# #linkedin API which returns the comments on an update returns the first or the last 100 comments of user?

Tags: linkedin-api

Last time as I saw the API (`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates/key={update-key}/update-comments?format=json`) returns the first 100 comments of users and ignores the recent comments if this number is reached.

1. I would like to be sure if the API is modified or it is the same? I would like to know if those comments which the API returns are the first or the last 100 comments?
2. Is there any way to retrieve only the last comments if this number is reached?

Answer (score 0):

According to [LinkedIn API Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#get_update_comments) it does not seem like pagination is currently supported:

> A maximum of 100 comments will be returned.

Also judging from the [REST console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) when selecting template query for `Get comments for a specific company update`, there does not seem to be any additional field in the GET query to filter the results.

My guess is that it's still a work in progress.

Comment: Thank a lot to reply me Michal, If I understand it's still the same behavior i.e API returns maxi 100 comments first

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I would keep a close eye to it though - it hasn't been that long since they started the transition to the new version of the API (mid February). Even though they said that the `companies` portion will remain the same, I would expect some movement (at least the pagination makes sense...).